# How to show blue arrow in Android app like Google Maps?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2, android-location, compass-geolocation

How to achieve that of the Google Maps app for android (below figure) for my own app which contains a map?

**Updates**

It appears I can achieve my goal using MyLocationOverlay + MapView according to [this](http://joshclemm.com/blog/?p=148). However, it is not very clear how to make MyLotionOverlay works with MapFragment and Google Maps Android API v2 (which I'm using) after my searches yet.

Also, it appears that I can get the blue bubble setMyLocationEnabled(true) of GoogleMap class.
What about the arrow?

**Updates**

I did see the arrow head only once a in long while and it's not responsive at all to my change of aim, in my app actually. Now I'm more confused what's going on.
Any ideas, anyone?

What I currently have:
[image]

The blue arrow I want to achieve is as below:
[image]

Comment: The blue dot changes to blue arrow when you move.

Comment: Hi @MaciejGórski, possibly. However, it changes to an arrow after a few seconds without me moving at all for Google Maps app, can I achieve the same?

Comment: @fuzzybee, hmmmm....Any luck? i am looking for a blue dot with an arrow!

Comment: have you still got the code for your advances?